# 'RegionProperties' object has no attribute 'mean_intensity'

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm having some issues with calculating mean instensity with skimage. All other prop regions (area, feret diameter, etc.) work fine so I am not sure what the issue is? I use Python 3.8.0 with skimage version 0.18.1. Based on the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.18.x/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=region%20props#regionprops) it should support the mean_intensity property. But I get this error message:

AttributeError: '<class 'skimage.measure._regionprops.RegionProperties'>' object has no attribute 'mean_intensity'

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: bug report to skimage project?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't accidentally upgraded your scikit-image version? The property was renamed `intensity_mean` in 0.19.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.
In[3]: skimage.__version__
Out[3]: '0.18.1'

Comment: Well, does `intensity_mean` work?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: ok that's really super weird. Does it have *any* attributes, e.g. `.area`? I have no idea what could be causing such a thing — I might suggest uninstall+reinstall.

Comment: Yes, area works, intensity_mean and mean_intensity do not. Probably a bug.

Comment: OooooooooOOOOOhhhh! This is an *unhelpful error message* issue, not a functionality issue: you *must* pass an `intensity_image=` argument, or `mean_intensity` doesn't make sense. It *should* ideally say "you didn't pass an intensity image", but it doesn't. ‍♂️ Anyway, here's the relevant issue in the repo: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5048

Comment: Apologies for the confusion! The renaming of the argument had me chasing a red herring.