# Regionprops in skimage does not return intensity_mean

Tags: python, scikit-image

Regionprops in skimage does not return intensity_mean and returns an error. A minimal example is here:

```
from skimage import data, util
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
img = util.img_as_ubyte(data.coins()) > 110
label_img = label(img, connectivity=img.ndim)
regions = regionprops(label_img)
for region in regions:
    print(region.area)
```

So the above example works, but the example below doesn't work:

```
from skimage import data, util
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
img = util.img_as_ubyte(data.coins()) > 110
label_img = label(img, connectivity=img.ndim)
regions = regionprops(label_img)
for region in regions:
    print(region.intensity_mean)
```

Honestly, I don't know what to try!

Comment: What is the error? Where can we see the data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `intensity_image=` as input to `regionprops` in order for `intensity_mean` and the other `intensity_` or `weighted_` attributes to be available. Unfortunately the error message is not very helpful as discussed in the comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042214/regionproperties-object-has-no-attribute-mean-intensity/76054663?noredirect=1#comment134240459_76054663). There is an open issue in the scikit-image repository to discuss this: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5048